# Debuggerproblem

Tags: iphone, json

I have problem ..
i get debugerror i will used in json

```
2009-02-13 18:32:17.405 xxxxxxxx[1491:20b] *** -[NsDecimalNumber length]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc3f10ff0
2009-02-13 18:32:17.406 xxxxxxxx[1491:20b] *** Terminating app due to
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NsDecimalNumber length
]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc3f10ff0'
2009-02-13 18:32:17.406 xxxxxxxx[1491:20b] Stack: (
2417225995,
2527100475,
2417255178,
2417248524,
2417248722,
22199,
9853,
816111650,
816149355,
2458333742,
2416728869,
2416729304,
827745792,
827745989,
816114848,
816160924,
9628,
9482
)
```

please send solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get a lenght of an object that is `NSDecimalNumber`, but `NSDecimalNumber` doesn't have such a property. So the bug in your code is in one of the rows you call `something.length` or `[something length]`.

[NSDecimalNumber documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).